# Kentico 9 - separate MVC application - authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

What is the recommended approach to using Kentico user roles and authentication/authorization using Kentico 9, MVC stand alone application?

Is it possible to use the Kentico role attributes for controller methods?

What part of the API is used to authenticate and check authentication in this scenario?

It looks to me like this is not yet possible, and I am about to roll my own solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It`s not officially supported (yet). You can see list of supported and unsupported features (for new Kentico9 MVC) [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Supported+and+unsupported+Kentico+features+on+MVC+sites).
Of course you can still use Kentico API (Membership library) to make your own auth logic which fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will work (I don't know how much MVC supports the old providers), but you may try to use the same membership and role provider configuration in your web.config as for the admin application.

Kentico 10 will provide validated membership features through a brand new identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="somerole")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

This work perfect in my tests... I'm using forms authentication.